# Solving distribution using conditional probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

A dice is tossed untill 3 even numbers apear. Let Y be the number of times "1" showed up. Find the distribution of Y+3.

My idea was:
Let L be the number of tosses, i managed to get that L is distributed negetive binominially, and Y|L is distributed binominially with L-3 as the number of trials and p=1/2. Adding all p(Y=k-3|L=n)*p(L=n) should get me p(Y+3=k), but im having a hard time solving this sum. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A die is tossed until the third `even` result occurs and we count the rolls of `1` among them.   We know the count for rolls, $L$, is negative binomial $(3, 1/2)$ and the count for `1` among those rolls, $Y$, is conditionally binomial $(L-3, 1/3)$ for a given $L$, but let us *not focus on that distraction*.

Instead let us count only rolls of `1`, `2`, `4`, or `6` and ask: What is the distribution for *that* count until the third `even` result ?

---

$Y$ is the count of `1` before the third even roll.   We aren't interested in results of `3` or `5` so... let us ignore those sides whenever they turn up and only count the rolls of interest. On the rolls we don't ignore, the results from `1`,`2`,`4`,`6` each still occur without bias, so we are effectively rolling a fair four-sided die.   $Y+3$ is the count of rolls of interest until the third even result.

---

$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=y) &= \sum_{x=y+3}^\infty\mathsf P(Y=y,X=x)
\\ &=\sum_{x=y+3}^\infty \dfrac{(x-1)!~1^y3^32^{x-3-y}}{y!~2!~(x-3-y)!~6^x}
\\ &= \text{can be done but let's do it the easy way}
\\[3ex] \mathsf P(Y+3=k) &= {\text{effectively the probability for rolling }\\k-3\text{ ones before the third not-one on a four sided die.}}
\end{align}$

Comment: And why would we do so? Im having a hard time to follow..could you ezplain further? Thanks

Comment: $Y$ is the count of `1` before the third even.  We aren't interested in results of `3` or `5` so... let us ignore those sides whenever they turn up and only count the rolls of interest. On the rolls we don't ignore, the results from `1`,`2`,`4`,`6` each still occur without bias, so we are effectively rolling a fair four-sided die.   $Y+3$ is the count of rolls of interest until the third even result.